# draggable accuracy in jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Hi: I am running of a problem when I am trying to make a special drag drop in JQuery.In few words.

from the link above you can see that when we drag the boxes to the dropping areas (the left red boxes) they ( I mean the droppable boxes) does not seem to be activated unless the dragged box reach the center of the target ( the droppable box) element which is seem to be a problem in the JQuery itself !?

Another thing, which is there is no control over the draggables element as they hover upon the droppables, for example, Can I make the draggables ( not the droppable ) become small AS THEY ENTER THE DROPPABLE AREAS !

Any help, ideas, or clues will be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery droppable has an [option 'tolerance'](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#option-tolerance) that controls this.  It has 4 settings: fit, intersect, pointer, touch.  From your description, it looks like you want 'touch'- the draggable is considered overlapping as soon as it touches the droppable.

```
$('.drop_area').droppable(
    { tolerance: 'touch' }
);
```

Comment: Looks like the right solution to me.  Basher, you can also use the "over" event to perform some actions when a draggable is hovering over a droppable element.  In this case, you could use it to add a height/width to the draggable to reduce its size, then use the out event to set the size back again.